# Kafka Stream giving weird output

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm playing around with Kafka Streams trying to do basic aggregations (for the purpose of this question, just incrementing by 1 on each message). On the output topic that receives the changes done to the `KTable`, I get really weird output:

```
@B�
@C
@C�
@D
@D�
@E
@E�
@F
@F�
```

I recognize that the "�" means that it's printing out some kind of character that doesn't exist in the character set, but I'm not sure why. Here's my code for reference:

```java
public class KafkaMetricsAggregator {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String bootstrapServers = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "my-kafka-ip:9092";

        final Properties streamsConfig = new Properties();
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "metrics-aggregator");
        // Where to find Kafka broker(s).
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        // Specify default (de)serializers for record keys and for record values.
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        // Records should be flushed every 10 seconds. This is less than the default
        // in order to keep this example interactive.
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
        // For illustrative purposes we disable record caches
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
        // Class to extract the timestamp from the event object
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, "my.package.EventTimestampExtractor");

        // Set up serializers and deserializers, which we will use for overriding the default serdes
        // specified above.
        final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer(), new JsonDeserializer());
        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final Serde<Double> doubleSerde = Serdes.Double();

        final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

        final KTable<String, Double> aggregatedMetrics = builder.stream(jsonSerde, jsonSerde, "test2")
            .groupBy(KafkaMetricsAggregator::generateKey, stringSerde, jsonSerde)
            .aggregate(
                () -> 0d,
                (key, value, agg) -> agg + 1,
                doubleSerde,
                "metrics-table2");

        aggregatedMetrics.to(stringSerde, doubleSerde, "metrics");

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfig);
        // Only clean up in development
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();

        // Add shutdown hook to respond to SIGTERM and gracefully close Kafka Streams
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
      }

}
```

EDIT: Using `aggregatedMetrics.print();` does print out the correct output to the console:

```
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000002]: my-generated-key , (43.0<-null)
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Serdes.Double() for your values, that uses a binary efficient encoding [1] for the serialised values and that's what you're seeing on your topic. To get human-readable numbers on the console, you'd need to instruct the consumer to use the DoubleDeserializer too.

[1] https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e31c0c9bdbad432bc21b583bd3c084f05323f642/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/DoubleSerializer.java#L29-L44

Answer (score 0):

Specify DoubleDeserializer as value deserializer at consumer's command line as shown below

`--property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.DoubleDeserializer`